# How to specify the "Content-Type" and "Accept" on FormRequest?

Tags: python, scrapy

Using the `RequestForm`, I need to specify that the Content-Type is `application/json; charset=UTF-8` and Accept is `*/*`.
How to do this?

Currently, my code looks like this:

```
yield scrapy.FormRequest(url='...',
                         formdata={
                             ...
                         },
                         cookies={...},
                         callback=self.parse_second)
```

Using browser, the request is:

```
POST /PaginasPublicas/_SBC.aspx/pesquisaLoteIntegracaoTPCL HTTP/1.1
Host: geosampa.prefeitura.sp.gov.br
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 118
Accept: */*
Origin: http://geosampa.prefeitura.sp.gov.br
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.94 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Referer: http://geosampa.prefeitura.sp.gov.br/PaginasPublicas/_SBC.aspx
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: pt-BR,pt;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4,ar;q=0.2,de;q=0.2,es;q=0.2,fr;q=0.2,it;q=0.2,ja;q=0.2,pl;q=0.2,tr;q=0.2,zh-TW;q=0.2
Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=bvvghxvsxgwzuyaudsqn5m5q
```

Comment: Basically, your question is answered correctly as needed.
You can see that what you asked is achieved correctly, your request sample shows that, If you need more help open a new question regarding the same with your errors.

Answer (score 0):

Your request should be like this:

```
yield FormRequest(..., headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json','charset':'UTF-8'})
```

Comment: you asked how to add headers to a POST request, and @Murali answered, If you need help with a specific POST request, you should share all the information because errors could happen for different reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Scrapy Request has a field [headers](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#scrapy.http.Request.headers) which is use to define explicit headers. This will work for you.

```
yield scrapy.FormRequest(url='...',
                     formdata={
                         ...
                     },
                     cookies={...}, headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json','charset':'UTF-8'},
                     callback=self.parse_second)
```